# ggtag-find-file seems to override select-window

Tags: emacs, elisp, global, emacs24

Let's say I have a function:

```html
(defun test (file line)
  (let ((currwin (get-buffer-window  (current-buffer))))
    (other-window 1)
    ;; (find-file filename)
    (ggtags-find-file file)
    (goto-line line)
    (select-window currwin)
    )
  )
```

This uses the new `ggtags` function, from the `ggtags` package.

What happens us that `ggtags-find-file` shows in "my window" but `goto-line` happens in other window (where the `ggtags-find-file` is supposed to be displayed)!

Now lets take an interesting variation:

```html
(defun test (file line)
  (let (currwin (get-buffer-window  (current-buffer)))
;;    (setq currwin (get-buffer-window  (current-buffer))) ;; (A)
    (other-window 1)
    ;; (find-file filename)
    (ggtags-find-file file)
    (goto-line line)
    ;;    (select-window currwin)  ;; (B)
;;    (other-window 1)    ;; (C)
    )
  )
```

In this variation (actually a typo as I forgot the outer enclosing ()),
I got the display happening in the "other-window" but `goto-line` did not work. [As a matter of fact, it worked in the buffer below it!]

More interesting part is that if I uncomment (C) OR (A) & (B), I go back to the earlier state.

It seems that `ggtags-find-file` is a spawned off process.

I did this experiment:

```html
(defun test (file line)
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Test*"
    (ggtags-find-file file)
    (goto-line line)
    )
  (switch-to-buffer-other-window "*Test*")
  )
```

In this case, I see the *Test* displayed for a half-second and the `ggtags-file` displayed there.

Anyway advice, help, criticism are welcome!

N.B.
  I may be noted that if I used `find-file` all seems to be working!

Comment: The documentation of `find-file` specifically says that it switches to the new buffer.  What does `ggtags-find-file` say/do?

Comment: @AndrewSwann 
Somewhere deep down the ggtags.el file we make this call:

` (setq ggtags-global-start-file buffer-file-name)
........
    (ggtags-with-current-project
      (with-current-buffer (with-display-buffer-no-window
                             (compilation-start command 'ggtags-global-mode))
        (setq-local ggtags-process-environment env)
        (setq ggtags-global-last-buffer (current-buffer))))))`

Hope this helps...

Comment: Then it looks like you can just do `(set-buffer ggtags-global-last-buffer)` just before the `goto-line` in your first example.